# Why does svn checkout use the wrong URL?

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

Possibly a stupid question, but does anyone know of a reason why `svn checkout` might check out from an URL other than the one you specify please? I'm running this command:

```
svn co -r107616 https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/branches/carbon/3.2.0 r107616
```

However, an `svn info` in the `r107616` directory after checkout says:

```
Path: .
URL: https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/tags/carbon/3.2.0
Repository Root: https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2
Repository UUID: a5903396-d722-0410-b921-86c7d4935375
Revision: 107616
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: senaka
Last Changed Rev: 107616
Last Changed Date: 2011-06-10 07:51:44 +0100 (Fri, 10 Jun 2011)
```

The key thing to note is that the URL refers to the tag and not the branch. Any thoughts please?

For what it's worth, this is reproducible for me (I've tried it twice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goals you should use peg-revision.

```
svn co https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/branches/carbon/3.2.0@107616 r107616
```

More answers are here http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/pegrevs/

Comment: Interesting! I hadn't come across this at all when using SVN before, many thanks.